# Django Tutorial

Tags: python, django

I'm just starting with the Django tutorial. When I try to run  `python manage.py migrate`as they say, I get

```
Unknown command: 'migrate'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
```

I am in the directory right above manage.py. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: Follow the tutorial for 1.6. migrate was added only in 1.7. You would use `manage.py syncdb` in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be using the wrong Django version. You can figure out which version you're running by doing `python ./manage.py shell` and then inside the shell, type the following:

```
>>> import django
>>> django.VERSION
```

If your django version is less than 1.6, check the docs for the version applying to what you are running.

Previous versions of Django did not use the `migrate` command, unless you installed a third party module called `South`.

Comment: I'm on 1.6.1, and using Python 2.7.5